# Django sort filtered objects by other model's value

Tags: python, django, django-models, querying

i have following models and i filtered all **Songs** by Item's `object_id` field. But then i need to use **Item**'s `position` to sort them. Is there any way to filter Songs and filter it by `Items' position?

```py
class Chart(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=CONTENT_TYPE_LIMIT)

class Version(models.Model):
    chart = models.ForeignKey("Chart", related_name="versions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Item(models.Model):
    edition = models.ForeignKey(Version, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="items")
    object_id = models.UUIDField(db_index=True)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Now i get the `chart` first by `list_ids = chart.versions.last().items.all()` and to get Songs i run `Songs.objects.filter(id__in=list_ids)` But i need to do `order_by('position')` for this too. Maybe my approach of getting all Songs was wrong. Because Items's `object_id` must be a `Songs` id though it is intentionaly not a `ForeignKey` though.

Answer (score 0):

To order by a field in a different model, use the same syntax as when you are querying across model relations by using double underscore just as for filtering. Unfortunately, in your case, since there is no relation between the "Songs" and the "Item" models, it will not be possible to order by a field in "Item model".

Please refer to [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) for more info.